# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, exception, kotlin

I am developing new and I am reading JSON file from asset folder but I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at yodgorbek.komilov.runtastictask1.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.kt:45)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2164)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:765)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6154)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2643)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2348)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7124)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1008)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:804)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

below my code to gist

Comment: please post your json and pojo class as well

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @FurqanKhan My code very long thats why I have posted gistlist please check it stackoverflow did not allowed to post all thats why I shared as gist

Comment: @sashabeliy check `model` value is it null? `val model = gson.fromJson(loadJSONFromAssets(), NetworkResponse::class.java)`

Comment: @Basi How I will check it

Comment: using android studio debugger

Comment: I am using debugger json coming

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong key for members in your Group data class, it is **data** while in your json it shows the key is **members** 
use the following class and it will work

```
data class Group(
    @SerializedName("group_id")
    val group_id: Int,

    @SerializedName("group_name")
    val group_name: String,

    @SerializedName("members")
    val members: List<Member>

)
```

Comment: it is showing empty white screen what is your suggestion

Comment: because in your main activity xml you have not assinged the constraints to  list view, i would recommend to change constraint layout to linear layout

Comment: it is still the same i have changed to linearlayout vertical

Comment: what do you think main problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct key

```
data class Group(
@SerializedName("group_id")
val group_id: Int,

@SerializedName("group_name")
val group_name: String,

@SerializedName("data")
val members: List<Member>)
```

According to your json schema it should be

```
data class Group(
@SerializedName("group_id")
val group_id: Int,

@SerializedName("group_name")
val group_name: String,

@SerializedName("members")
val members: List<Member>)
```

Comment: it did not help

Comment: App is still crashing or some other error is coming?